# Probability of event happening before another.

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

A camera has been lost in the forest, a group of friends are organizing an expedition to find it back (*summary of the previous parts of the problem*). 
 
While searching for the camera, a parc ranger appears and tells the group that there has been 9 random sightings
of a wild boar in the past 2 days and that they must take extra caution.

Assume they will end their day of search in at most three more hours, **approximate the probability a wild boar appears before they find the camera during the next three hours**. State any assumptions used in the calculation.
I think the underlying distribution to describe the sighting of boars is an Exponential Distribution $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$, but the part that throws me of is how to take the finding of the camera into account 
($P(X < 3\mid Camera\ not\ found)$ ? ).
Note that the probability for finding (or not) the camera has not been previously given.. (Makes it all the more confusing to me)
Thank you :)

Comment: I would interpret the question as "suppose it takes exactly three hours to find the camera.  Approximate the probability that a wild boar appears during that three hour window."  Of course, this would be one of the assumptions that is made and should be listed as the problem requests.

Comment: That said, there will be *several* assumptions that need to be made to attempt this problem.  Perhaps the wild boar is active only during certain hours.  If all sightings took place in the late evening and our friends were searching at noon, perhaps the boar is not active at that time and wouldn't be seen.  Perhaps the boar was only seen in a certain part of the woods away from where they are searching.  Something else to consider is the number of people who reported they saw the boar compared to the number of people who didn't and at what time the people were present to have possibly seen...

Comment: Thank you! Would you say these assumptions would lead to compute the probability simply as $P(X < 3\mid Camera\ not\ found) = P(t < 3) = 1 - \lambda e^{-\lambda *3}$ (Exponential Distribution) ?

Comment: No, I would have used poisson distribution and looked at probability X>0 using an appropriate parameter for the distribution according to our assumptions, perhaps also multiplying by the probability that among those in the woods right now that it happened to be us that the boar appeared in front of